# Error: you have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, get, localhost

The error appears to be like this:

> Notice: Undefined index: JobID in C:\wamp\www\job.php on line 32
>   and line 32 is : $JobID=$_GET['JobID'];

I am trying to solve this for 10 days, reading different books of different authors. But I still don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])) //this is form action 
{
$result3 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members where user='$user'");
while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3))
{ 
$name=$row3['name'];
$user=$row3['user'];
$number=$row3['number'];
}
$numrows=mysql_num_rows($query);
if($numrows==0)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO applicant (user,name,number,)           VALUES('$user','$name','$number')";
 $result=mysql_query($sql);
 if($result){
 header('Location: thankyou2.php');
 } else {
 echo "Failure!";
}
}
}
else
{


$mysql_hostname = "localhost";
$mysql_user = "root";
$mysql_password = "";
$mysql_database = "abcdef";
$prefix = "";
$bd = mysql_connect($mysql_hostname, $mysql_user, $mysql_password) or        die("Could not connect database");
mysql_select_db($mysql_database, $bd) or die("Could not select database");
$JobID=$_GET['JobID'];
$job_sql="SELECT * FROM job WHERE JobID=$JobID";
$job_query = mysql_query($job_sql) or die(mysql_error());
$rsjob=mysql_fetch_assoc($job_query);
};
?>
<b><center><table class="bordered"> 
//Data will fetch in this table by GET method

<thead>
<?php echo $rsjob['jobname'];?></h1></font>
<tr>       
<th><font face="Script MT">Description</th>
<th><font face="Script MT">Details</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tr>
    <td>Name</td>
     <td><?php echo $rsjob['jobname'];?></td>
    </tr>        
<tr>

<td>Type</a></td>
<td><?php echo $rsjob['type'];?></td>
</tr>
</table><br>

<?php
if ($loggedin)
{
echo 
<<<_END
<form action="job.php" method="POST" name="jobapply">  
<input type="checkbox" name="termscondition"                  required/>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; I have read all the 
<a href="termscondition.html">Terms and Condition</a><br>  
<br><input type="submit" value="Apply"></form> 
_END;
 }
 else 
{

   echo '<center> please sign up and/or log in to   <strong>Apply</strong>.    </center>';

};
?>
```

Comment: Did you add ?JobID=1234 in your URI?

Comment: possible duplicate of [check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240873/check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server-version-for-the-right-syn)

Comment: how many questions dealing with the same will you post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31240873/check-the-manual-that-corresponds-to-your-mysql-server-version-for-the-right-syn try to learn

Comment: `JobID='$JobID'` should solve the query error and add checks.

Comment: Your code has a number of SQL injection vulnerabilities, which is likely to be exploited if you put this code on the internet. You can resolve this by casting strings containing numbers to integers, or using `mysql_real_escape_string()`, but it is better to switch to a database library that supports parameterisation. The library you are presently using is now deprecated anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
$JobID=$_GET['jobid'];
```

instead of

```
$JobID=$_GET['JobID'];
```

Comment: Hello Sir, I did it in small letters too. But no result.

Comment: please check with

if(isset($_GET['jobid'])){
  // your code her
}else{
  // Show some error to the user or try to deal with the missing parameter 
}

Answer (score 0):

```
$JobID=$_GET['JobID'];
```

that is brave. You shoudl check if the get-paramenter `JobID` is set. If not, don't excecut the rest of your code.

Beside that: you should make all the get-parameters in lowercase. Mixing that up could be a problem aswell.

```
if(isset($_GET['jobid'])){
  // your code her
}else{
  // Show some error to the user or try to deal with the missing parameter 
}
```